# Vue is not rendered in Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, vue.js, capybara

I'm trying to test Vue.js from Rspec with Capybara. My problem is: the body is empty.

I was looking info for a few days and all the solutions is to change the driver of Capybara. I tried all but the bug persists.

My rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

options = {js_errors: false}

Capybara.server = :puma
require 'rack_session_access/capybara'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods # this allows to use factory girl gem's methods
  # this is to test javascript with capybara  
end
```

Then I have a feature test in spec/features/

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/login_helper'

RSpec.feature "login", type: :feature, js: true do
  include LoginHelper

  before do
    login!
  end

  scenario 'a' do
    expect(true).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

And finally, my login helper when I have the error.

```
require 'rails_helper'

module LoginHelper
    def login!
        visit root_path
        print page.html
        fill_in "username", with: "aaa"
        click_button "Entrar"
    end
end
```

In the helper I try to visit the root_path, get the input and then fill with some mock data.

In the console, the test provides me the following error:

```
Failure/error: fill_in "username", with: "aaa"

Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find visible field "username" that is not disabled
```

I print the page.html before the fill_in and I have

In the vue.app I'm using

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `poltergeist` driver which has a few issues, and then you've also turned off reporting of js errors on the poltergeist driver which will just hide even more problems.  The `poltergeist` driver uses PhantomJS as its "browser" which ends up being approximately equivalent to a 6 year old version of Safari. This means it has no support for ES6+ and any code that uses features provided in ES6+ would need to be transpiled and polyfilled to ES5 levels.  Additionally any code that used `let` or `const` without being transpiled will cause PhantomJS (and hence poltergeist) to silently fail and not evaluate any of the JS.

Another issue you may be running into is the difference between development and test environments with regards to the treatment of JS assets. In development mode each JS asset is served as a separate file so an error in one file won't prevent parsing/execution of a different file. In test mode the JS assets are concatenated into one file, which means a single error in any of the JS files can/will cause JS from other files to never be evaluated.

If you really want to stay with `poltergeist` you're going to need to look at the browsers console in development mode and fix any JS errors shown there, then make sure all your files are being transpiled and polyfilled to ES5 compatibility levels, and you should also turn on `js_errors` reporting so you're not actively hiding problems. 
From a compatibility with modern apps perspective, a much better solution is to swap to using the `selenium` driver with either Chrome of Firefox (both of which can be run headless if needed/wanted). This would also mean you'd actually be testing with versions of browsers your users would possibly be currently using.

Comment: I changed to `headless_chrome` and now I have a `Net::ReadTimeout`. I think I have some problem with the test server

Comment: @DavidLuque Which would generally mean you aren't using an up to date version of `chromedriver` but without more details it's impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score -1):

I switched to selenium headless-chrome instead of Poltergeist/Phantom JS and it worked